# I have windows 7 os installed in virtual box .I want to install software in this os .How to do that?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have windows 7 os installed in virtual box .I want to install software in this os .How to do that? how to locate setup file in drive .

Comment: What do you mean, please can you elaborate?  It's just Windows7, you can install an exe or msi file as normal.  Do you mean how to get the exe/msi installer file to the guest OS?  Is the Virtual Machine connected to a network, does it use shared folders?

Comment: yes u got it right .. i want to install exe file in guest os .havnt check with share .

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand your comment.  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: scenario is i have installed windows 7 in virtual machine .     i want to install exe file in this windows 7 os .How to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the installer (.exe) inside the guest OS. There are several ways to do this:

1. download from the internet inside the guest OS
2. connect a USB flash drive, copy the installer onto it, and make the USB drive visible inside the guest OS. If you are running linux as host, you need to run VirtualBox as root otherwise the USB drives are not visible.
3. enable folder sharing between the guest and host OS and copy the .exe into the shared folder