# How to install a program in a Windows 7 virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine setup on a Windows 10 host using Virtual Box.

What is the best way to transfer and install a large (8GB file) on my Windows 7 virtual machine?

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? Please don't do that, read and take note of [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). If you have new information you should edit it into the original question instead of asking a new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have windows 7 os installed in virtual box .I want to install software in this os .How to do that?](http://superuser.com/questions/1101860/i-have-windows-7-os-installed-in-virtual-box-i-want-to-install-software-in-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some ways to do that...

some of them need to install extension pack. (you can download it from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads))
those which need extension pack are :

enable copy-paste (shared clipboard)

enable drag and drop

enable USB devices (copy your file to a flash drive, then connect it to a VM)

you can enable and disable all the above suggestions from this menu on the top of the VM window:

[image]

if you dont want to install extension pack, you can just share the folder in your host, and then access it in the VM. (for this solution, you should configure the network section in order to have VM and host in same network)

Comment: yes but pendrive is not visible in win 7

Comment: @SushantShinde - Did you attach the USB drive to the virtual machine?  If you don't know how to do this, read the manual for VirtualBox, it explain how to do that.

Comment: @SushantShinde I've added more explaination. just click on your pendrive in the shown list.

Comment: excellent guys .. u saved my day .. works fyn @komeil sh .. thank ramhound Thank bitten fleax..

Answer (score 1):

A good way to transfer a large file is to create a "Shared Folder".

This is straight from the documentation:

> There are several ways in which shared folders can be set up for a
>   particular virtual machine:
>
> In the window of a running VM, you can select "Shared folders" from
>   the "Devices" menu, or click on the folder icon on the status bar in
>   the bottom right corner.
>
> If a VM is not currently running, you can configure shared folders in
>   each virtual machine's "Settings" dialog.
>
> From the command line, you can create shared folders using VBoxManage,
>   as follows:
>
> VBoxManage sharedfolder add "VM name" --name "sharename" --hostpath
>   "C:\test" See Section 8.29, “VBoxManage sharedfolder add/remove” for
>   details.

Source: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Or if that is too much effort you can try this: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-dnd

Comment: i have windows 10 laptop , i have installed win 7 in virtual box , i want to install one software in windows 7 rather than windows 10.How to install that software in win 7

Comment: Go into Virtual Box and `Start` the Windows 7 virtual machine. Then when it launches into the virtual machine, go to Internet Explorer and download the program you want to run. Then run it.

Comment: its huge software . approx 8 gb

Comment: Ahh, I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @SushantShinde - Your question as currently written is extremely broad.  You have asked a question, if somebody knows the answer to it, they will submit an answer.  You don't need to ask us "to help you out", we already know you want help, comments asking for help (again, and again) are not constructive.